# Finding relative rotation between two cameras

Tags: opencv, camera, rotation, computer-vision

I have two images I1 and I2, with both extrinsic and intrinsic camera parameters(R1,t1,R2,t2 and K). For a simpler case when cameras have zero translation, I can find the relative rotation between two cameras using;

```
R = (R1.I) * R2
```

But if they have translations t1 and t2, then above will fail. We'll need to apply negative translations to bring them to world origin and then above will work. What I don't understand is on what should I apply negative translations?

Answer (score 3):

The relative rotation from the first to the second camera will not change when you have a translation between the cameras. When the pose of the first camera is **(R1, t1)** and of the second **(R2, t2)**, then you can compute the rotation from one to two as

```
R_diff = R1.inv * R2,
```

(which you wrote above) and the translation, which is a bit more tedious to derive, is

```
t_diff = R1.inv * (t2 - t1).
```

From this, you can then compute the pose of the second camera from the pose of the first camera as

```
R2 = R1 * R_diff,
t2 = R1 * t_diff + t1.
```

I was not sure what you mean by "above will fail" in the case of non-zero translations, so I hope I understood your question correctly.